# Why pt-duplicate-key-checker suggests removing a composite index?

Tags: mysql, index, percona-tools

Here's a snippet from the output of the Percona Tool `pt-duplicate-key-checker` which searches for redundant indexes:

```
# Key myidx ends with a prefix of the clustered index
# Key definitions:
#   KEY `myidx` (`bar`,`foo`)
#   PRIMARY KEY (`foo`),
# Column types:
#         `bar` mediumint(8) unsigned not null default '0'
#         `foo` mediumint(8) unsigned not null auto_increment
# To shorten this duplicate clustered index, execute:
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`mytable` DROP INDEX `myidx`, ADD INDEX `myidx` (`bar`);
```

Why does the tool suggest this? Can't the original composite index be useful?

As far as I understand, an index on `bar` would be worth of deletion given a PK `(bar,foo)`, but it is not the case here.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable;` output as well?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access anymore to the db, I'll try to find another example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary key is a part of any secondary key in InnoDB.

Comment: Found a reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-extensions.html

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the analysis given by the tool.

When I see `INDEX(bar, foo)`, I assume there is some query that needs those two columns, in that order, to be in this composite index.

The fact that `foo` is the PK, and `INDEX(bar)` is identical to the above index is irrelevant.

When I see just `INDEX(bar)`, I assume there is some query that needs `(bar)` without `id`.

When I see both, I will say that the shorter one is 'redundant' and recommend removing it.

Furthermore, "To shorten this duplicate clustered index" is *wrong*.  `INDEX(bar)` is no 'shorter' than `INDEX(bar, foo)`.  *And* it is not a "clustered index.  Only the PK is "clustered".

If it were `UNIQUE(bar, foo)`, then I would recommend changing `UNIQUE` to `INDEX`.  This is so that `INSERTs` won't have to do an unnecessary uniqueness check.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Are you saying that both the MySQL docs and the Percona tool are wrong? (I'm not trying to polemize, I have a genuine interest to find the correct answer.)

Comment: @dr01 MySQL docs agree with Rick's answer.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Can you please point where? So, it's the PT who is wrong? It's a pretty bold statement given that it was developed by MySQL experts.

Comment: The link you posted in your comment in the other answer explains a lot. Why do you think Rick's answer disagrees with that explanation?

Comment: As for the "developed by MySQL experts", sure it was. It doesn't mean the tool is infallible. We can always send them a bug report so they fix this edge case.

Comment: I was going to encourage @Rick and you to do so.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - I have already reached out to Percona for clarification.  I have used MySQL for many years more than Percona has existed.  Yes, they are experts, but so am I.  I expect this to be minor oversight on the part of the one(?) person who wrote the tool.  I don't say "it's wrong" without thinking carefully first.

Comment: @RickJames Would you be so kind to later update your answer with the reply you receive from Percona? I'm interested. And +1 for now.

Comment: @dr01 - Yes.  I will update it, or do whatever clarification is needed.  If you want to, you could file a bug report with Percona.

Comment: @RickJames does this post clarify? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204076/why-pt-duplicate-key-checker-suggests-removing-a-composite-index/205565#205565? 
To be straight, I don't personally have the knowledge to get to the bottom of this for you but I should be able to facilitate a discussion via the Percona Forum with some of our advanced developers if that would help. Not to undermine dba.stackexchange, but from Percona's PoV, the discussion isn't trackable here, which is important for software maintenance. Once resolved I can post the definitive answer however it falls.

Comment: @percona-lorraine - That Answer nicely confirms the structure and use of a secondary index.  It does not say, but perhaps supports, my contention that the secondary index should _not_ be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Let's create a simple table and see what MySQL (5.7.20 MySQL Community Server) has to tell us:

```
mysql> create table test_dupe_key (foo int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, bar int unsigned not null, random int unsigned not null default 0, key(bar, foo)) engine=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> show create table test_dupe_key\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test_dupe_key
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test_dupe_key` (
  `foo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bar` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `random` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`foo`),
  KEY `bar` (`bar`,`foo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test_dupe_key(bar) values (1), (2), (3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test_dupe_key;
+-----+-----+--------+
| foo | bar | random |
+-----+-----+--------+
|   1 |   1 |      0 |
|   2 |   2 |      0 |
|   3 |   3 |      0 |
+-----+-----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is a simple query that can be read from the index:

```
mysql> explain format=json select foo, bar from test_dupe_key\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
EXPLAIN: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "1.60"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "test_dupe_key",
      "access_type": "index",
      "key": "bar",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "bar",
        "foo"
      ],
      "key_length": "8",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 3,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 3,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "using_index": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "1.00",
        "eval_cost": "0.60",
        "prefix_cost": "1.60",
        "data_read_per_join": "48"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "foo",
        "bar"
      ]
    }
  }
}
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

This shows that the key bar is used and has 2 key parts, both being read to produce a key length of 8 (2x4).
Now let's switch the composite key for a single field and check again:

```
mysql> alter table test_dupe_key drop key bar, add key(bar);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain format=json select foo, bar from test_dupe_key\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
EXPLAIN: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "1.60"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "test_dupe_key",
      "access_type": "index",
      "key": "bar",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "bar"
      ],
      "key_length": "4",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 3,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 3,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "using_index": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "1.00",
        "eval_cost": "0.60",
        "prefix_cost": "1.60",
        "data_read_per_join": "48"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "foo",
        "bar"
      ]
    }
  }
}
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Only the key parts and length now change, which is as expected, but it is still an index read.
If we turn this into a range query on the PK field with a constraint on the indexed field let's see what happens:

```
mysql> explain format=json select foo, bar from test_dupe_key where bar = 1 and foo > 0\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
EXPLAIN: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "1.20"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "test_dupe_key",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "PRIMARY",
        "bar"
      ],
      "key": "bar",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "bar",
        "foo"
      ],
      "key_length": "8",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "using_index": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "1.00",
        "eval_cost": "0.20",
        "prefix_cost": "1.20",
        "data_read_per_join": "16"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "foo",
        "bar"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "((`stack_204076`.`test_dupe_key`.`bar` = 1) and (`stack_204076`.`test_dupe_key`.`foo` > 0))"
    }
  }
}
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

The query planner has considered the PK for the query, but chosen the index for `bar`, which now has an interesting change to the previous index read as we can see that it now shows as 2 key parts again and a length of 8:

```
  "key": "bar",
  "used_key_parts": [
    "bar",
    "foo"
  ],
  "key_length": "8"
```

This tells us that MySQL has accessed the PK that is automatically contained in the secondary index

Comment: Nicely done forensics.